# Management software with black box database

Tags: javascript, php, database

I need to develop a management software and its database but I'm not allowed to ever look at any specific database entries in the database. The software is only going to be used from executives of the firm and the database will only be filled with confidential entries.

What is the best way to create such a "black box database" while ensuring it can always be debugged in case of an unexpected error? Since there is no way to ever look at the database entries I don't see a good way to be able to fix errors once they occur due to false entries or unexpected behaviour.

Is there any known best-case scenario for such a task?

Comment: Develop exclusively against a dummy database, and ensure all records are obfuscated in any and all logs…?

Comment: That's the plan I had but what can I do if for some reason an entry that is made ends up throwing any kind of error? 
There would be no way for me to find out what exactly causes the problem. I couldn't delete the faulty entry as I couldn't analyse the entries and I wouldn't know what exactly to fix.

Comment: Lots of validation to expect entries to conform to certain rules and lots of unit tests? And if it fails in production, try to sleuth out the problem from the obfuscated log files, which would hopefully give enough hints? If not, and the only way to debug is to look at the actual values which you're not supposed to do, I don't see a way out of that conundrum.

Comment: I see, that's sadly exactly what i feared to be the answer to my problem. I'll leave the question open for now in case anyone still has a magical way of solving this problem. Thanks alot deceze.

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems to pretty much come down to:

1. Get a complete specification about the expected data and behaviour.
2. Implement lots of validation against this specification.
3. Develop against a good dummy database which mimics the production data, with nonsense values obviously.
4. Lots of unit tests.

*In theory*, this should be sufficient to develop such software, which will then be run by somebody else somewhere else, which you don't need to worry about. *In practice* of course you may have to deal with bug reports which may hinge on actual production data. To be able to debug such cases "anonymously", you'll need to invest into a good logging layer. The logs should be informative enough to allow debugging, while obfuscating any and all actually sensitive info. A good validation layer can greatly help there. E.g. a log entry akin to this can be useful in itself:

```
Failed to foobar because username '●●●●●●●●●●' (string)
of record 670c55b0-177b-0139-f2a7-784f435149ee didn't conform to
rule 42 (/\d+\w+$/).
Stack trace:
   function baz(..) file x.y line 69
   ...
```

This basically doesn't give you any sensitive information, but worst case you can at least use it to talk to the actual user and tell them why the system failed and either instruct them how to correct the data, or get them to tell you more about the data.